# Progress bar in Sublime Text with Python

Tags: python, progress-bar, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am using the powerful Sublime Text 3 editor on MacOSX to run python codes. I want to display a progress bar of a for loop, and the following command:

```
sys.stdout.write('\rProgress : %03.2f %%' % (100*float(i)/(N)))
sys.flush()
```

does not clear the previously printed line in the output window as expected (`\r`) but produces `N` lines:

```
Progress : 0.25 %
Progress : 0.50 %
Progress : 0.75 %
Progress : 1.00 %
Progress : 1.25 %
Progress : 1.50 %
Progress : 1.75 %
Progress : 2.00 %
Progress : 2.25 %
Progress : 2.50 %
...
```

Which is not really nice to read – I conclude that the output window might be read-only.

Does anyone have suggestions to improve the use of progress bars in Sublime Text?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking - did you mean that due to the large amount of lines, that the output looks really "spammy", thus causing unpleasant outputs?

Comment: Yes, I did mean that. I edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Sublime's output panel. The panel is not a true console or terminal, and among other differences does not interpret escape sequences such as `\r` and `\b` (`\n` *is* interpreted correctly, however). If you want to see how exactly it works, install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer), then open `Packages/Default/exec.py`.

In order to get this to work, you'll need to create a new [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) to run it in Terminal. Due to the vagaries of OS X, you'll need to create two files. The first is a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e '    
  on run parameters        
    tell application "Terminal"            
      activate            
      do script with command "/path/to/python " & parameters        
    end tell    
  end run
' $@
```

Change `/path/to` with your actual path to `python` (or `python3`). Save it wherever you want as `PythonTerminal.sh`. Next, select **`Tools -> Build System -> New Build System`** and paste in the following:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["/bin/sh /path/to/Python3Terminal.sh \"$file\""],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

Again, change `/path/to` to the actual path to `PythonTerminal.sh`. Save the file as `Packages/User/PythonTerminal.sublime-build` (it should automatically open the correct directory when saving).

Finally, select **`Tools -> Build System -> PythonTerminal`**, switch to your Python file, and build with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. A new Terminal window will open and your progress bar should run.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a visual progress bar using:

- the [**mdpopups**](https://facelessuser.github.io/sublime-markdown-popups/) library
- `sublime.set_timeout` or `sublime.set_timeout_async` *( see: [**Sublime Module**](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime) )*

---

---

## Demo:

[image: Demo]

---

---

## Code:

## [@ GitHub](https://github.com/Enteleform/-SCRIPTS-/tree/master/SublimeText/%5BMisc%5D/%5BProof%20Of%20Concept%5D%20Progress%20Bar)

*( run the plugin by typing `Progress Bar Demo` @ the Command Palette )*

---

---

## Notes:

There is a [**css file**](https://github.com/Enteleform/-SCRIPTS-/blob/master/SublimeText/%5BMisc%5D/%5BProof%20Of%20Concept%5D%20Progress%20Bar/ProgressBarDemo/ProgressBarDemo_ProgressBar.css) that controls the style of `mdpopups`.
For some reason, the `color` property isn't having any effect.

Also, `mdpopups.show_popup`'s `location` parameter takes `-1` for the popup to be set at the caret position.
Otherwise, I'm not sure how `location` affects the popup, since it only takes a single integer value.

I've inquired about these issues at the following thread:

## [[Proof Of Concept] Visual Progress Bar](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/proof-of-concept-visual-progress-bar/18803)

Comment: Wow, good job. I didn't even know this was possible. I want to give a try to `mdpopups`

Comment: This looks really great ! I'm quite a newbie (sorry), but if I understand well: this can be used as a Sublime Text plugin, but is it possible to include it into a external/personal python code ?

Comment: @Léonard : The script I wrote is for integration with SublimeText plugins. I think the only way to track progress in regular python code would be an approach more along the lines of [__r-stein's answer__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36234502/4955183). You would, of course, have to refactor it to exclude the SublimeText-specific aspects and convert it's functionality to console output.

Answer (score 7):

As another alternative solution **you can use status bar**. When you you set the status bar message the previous text is cleared. *Package control* also uses status bar while installing packages.

Example:

[image: Sublime text progress bar using status bar]

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
import time

class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, args):
        sublime.set_timeout_async(self.test,1)

    def test(self):
        i=80
        while i <= 100:
            sublime.status_message('%03.2f %%' % i)
            time.sleep(0.15)
            i+=0.25
        sublime.status_message('100% Stackoverflow!')
```

Comment: Thanks man! This is a nice implementation too, probably more useful for something running asynchronously that doesn't need as much of a pronounced visual reference. Maybe an `mdpopup` notification on completion? : )

Comment: Cool :) Regarding the bounty, I will award it Sunday or Monday (due to stackoverfow rules I have to wait 24 hours before awarding it)

Comment: Awesome, didn't realize there was a bounty. Much appreciated : )

Answer (score 7):

Taking a look at `sublime.py` we see that the `flush` method actually does nothing:

```py
class _LogWriter:
    def flush(self):
        pass

    def write(self, s):
        sublime_api.log_message(s)

sys.stdout = _LogWriter()
sys.stderr = _LogWriter()
```

However I would not recommend to use the console for user outputs anyway. Usually you use output panels/views or status messages.

Status messages are easier to use, but less powerful. sergioFC demonstrated this in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36230019/5963435).

This demonstrates how to use an output panel. It is very flexible, but you must write your own text command to insert the text. This is necessary, because you need an edit object to change the content of the view.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class MyInsertProgressBarCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, value):
        view = self.view
        width, _ = view.viewport_extent()
        em_width = view.em_width()
        # the number of columns are the width divided by the width of a char
        # subtract two to add a little border
        columns = int(width / em_width) - 2

        # subtract two, because we surround it with [ and ]
        bar_length = columns - 2
        # calculate the size of the filled and the remaining part
        filled_length = int(bar_length * value / 100)
        remaining_length = bar_length - filled_length
        # assemble the string for the progress bar
        text = "[{0}{1}]\n".format("=" * filled_length, "." * remaining_length)
        # add the text for the percentages
        if value >= 100:
            percentage_text = "finished!"
        else:
            percentage_text = "{:3.2f} %".format(value)
        text += " " * (columns - len(percentage_text)) + percentage_text

        # replace the content of the view
        view.replace(edit, sublime.Region(0, view.size()), text)
        # reset sels
        view.sel().clear()
        view.sel().add(sublime.Region(0, 0))


class ProgressBarCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        self.window.create_output_panel("progess_bar")
        self.window.run_command("show_panel", {"panel": "output.progess_bar"})

        def test_progress_bar():
            import random
            test_progress_bar.value += 2 * random.random()
            if test_progress_bar.value >= 100:
                self.finish_progress()
                return
            self.show_progress(test_progress_bar.value)

            sublime.set_timeout(test_progress_bar, 100)
        test_progress_bar.value = 0

        sublime.set_timeout_async(test_progress_bar, 1)

    def show_progress(self, progess):
        view = self.window.find_output_panel("progess_bar")
        view.run_command("my_insert_progress_bar", {"value": progess})

    def finish_progress(self):
        self.show_progress(100)
        sublime.set_timeout(self._destroy, 5000)

    def _destroy(self):
        self.window.destroy_output_panel("progess_bar")
```

The output:

[image: Progress bar]

Comment: Cool solution : )  I wouldn't have thought of that.  I've been working with [__unicode generation__](https://github.com/Enteleform/Presentations/tree/master/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Sublime%20Text%20Plugins/2015-05-26#parkour) for a while, but your method gives me some insight into working with animated text. `mdpopups` is pretty cool for visual output too, I just tried it out for the first time in [__my answer__](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36234685/4955183)

Comment: @Enteleform Thanks =) I also was not aware, that it is possible to show a html window in a view. `mdpopups` seems to be a very nice addition for that feature.

Comment: Where should I have the code for MyInsertProgressBarCommand - do I add it to my project, or is it something I should add in the Sublime folder? If it's extending Sublime, where should there be a call to this module?
Also, please give an example of how to call these methods from the loop which progress we measure. Thanks.

Comment: @IliyanBobev If you want to use this, you need to add it to the Sublime Text package you are writing. Hence you can put into that package folder. If you are running a loop on a different thread you can just use the code inside `show_progress` (and `finish_progress`) to update the panel. If you are running on the main thread you need to rewrite your loop to call `sublime.set_timeout` as in this example, because you will block the whole UI otherwise and the progress bar won't show up anyway.

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is a way to keep the output from consuming multiple lines. You can print `\b` (the backspace character) as many times as there were previously printed characters. I wrote this as an example:

(Python 2.7.6)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time, sys

for i in range(1, 6):
    print(i, end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('\b', end='')
```

Try running that and you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but your proposition is quite close to my first try ( I was using `\r`, the return carriage). This solution works fine in a terminal, but doesn't work in the inside output window of Sublime Text. Here's the output of your solution: `12345[Finished in 2.6s]`.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I did not realize until now that you were talking about the output panel in Sublime Text. In a terminal session, this would print 1, replace it with 2, replace that with 3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use progressbar library. located here : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar/2.3-dev

Also you can install it from easy_install just type : `easy_install progressbar`

Example to use :

if you want simple progressbar with out information about function :

```
from progressbar import *
from time import sleep

progress = ProgressBar()
for i in progress(range(80)):
  sleep(0.01)
```

else if you want progressbar with information about function :

```
from progressbar import *
from time import sleep

widgets = ['Something: ', Percentage(), ' ', Bar(marker=RotatingMarker()),
           ' ', ETA(), ' ', FileTransferSpeed()]
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=widgets, maxval=10000000).start()
for i in range(1000000):
  # do something
  pbar.update(10*i+1)
  sleep(0.000001)
pbar.finish()
```